# Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'db_wire' in magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2.2.3

I am just executing this command line on console **php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated**  output of this command is **SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'db_wire'** what should i do and following is my env.php

```
array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'dbname' => 'db_wire',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'active' => '1',
  ),
),
```

I already created database with name 'db_wire'. I create a new database still it's giving same error .Please Help me.Many thanks

Comment: Did you created database db_wire?It seems database is not exist or you created database with another name.

Answer (score 1):

Please Create a Database with name 'db_wire' for your project, or if you already created any db for the project please replace it with 'db_wire'.

Answer (score 0):

If you dump a DB from another DB and both DB names are different, then check on your DB views. Rename old DB names to new ones inside the views. It fixed my issue.[image]